# LinearRegression() : R2 scoring with cross_val_score - weird results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, scoring

I'm using the cross_val_score() function to compute the `R2` coefficient of my fit.
Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
X = data.iloc[:,0:13]
y = data.iloc[:,13]
lin = LinearRegression()

MSE = cross_val_score(lin,X,y,scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',cv = 10)
MSE
array([  -9.28694671,  -14.15128316,  -14.07360615,  -35.20692433,
    -31.88511666,  -19.83587796,   -9.94726918, -168.37537954,
    -33.32974507,  -10.96041068])
MSE.mean()
-34.705255944525462

R2= cross_val_score(lin,X,y,cv = 10)
R2
array([ 0.73376082,  0.4730725 , -1.00631454,  0.64113984,  0.54766046,
    0.73640292,  0.37828386, -0.12922703, -0.76843243,  0.4189435 ])
R2.mean()
0.20252899006052702
```

I found these results very weird in particular the `R2` results:

- the 0 < R2 < 1?
- I found very weird that the mean squared result and the `R2` scores are very "scattered".

I perform this same regression task and compute the scores with "Rapidminer" and I get more "logical" results:

- Mean squared error = 24.218 +/- 10.413
- R2 = 0.848 +/- 0.066

NB : I precise that I get the same coefficients when fitting with Python and Rapidminer !!!!!!

Are they some errors in sklearn ?
Can someone explain me these weird scoring results with Python ?

Here you can find the link to my training dataset (.csv file) in order to replicate the behaviour I observe : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7xh5YMVeT6gf8NMS9fZgpOpe6kbw

Comment: Are you doing the cross-validation in Rapidminer? And is it performing 10-fold cv? Can you share your data so that others can replicate the behaviour.

Comment: Hi, Yes I perform 10-fold cv cross-validation in Rapidminer. How can I share my dataset (.csv file) : I don't find how to attach a file....

Comment: you can find the link to my training dataset (.csv file) in order to replicate the behaviour I observe in my question that I updated.